# Ajax Login that refresh only the logged div

Tags: javascript, authentication, ajax

Using Zoo Visitor ajax login or Ajax Auth, i manage well the ajax login witn EE. 
When the user is logged, how to refresh only the div that contains: welcome user you are logged.

```
 <div class="Welcome"><span>{username}</span>&nbsp;<a href="/logout">Logout</a></div><br />
```

Here is the Zoo Visitor Ajax login script:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                            $('#loginForm').ajaxForm({
                                    dataType: 'json',
                                    success: function(data) {
                                            if (data.success) {
                                                    alert('You are now logged in. You can add additional actions in the js script.');
                                            } else {
                                                    alert('Failed with the following errors: '+data.errors.login);
                                            }
                                    }
                            });
                    });
```

I guess i have to insert a javascript code inside:

```
alert('You are now logged in. You can add additional actions in the js script.');
```

I'm still learning javascript, using

```
setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML =
```

It's a good method??Does someone has some tips??
It is possible to use a Expression Engine function??

thanks,

Stéphane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `<div class="Welcome">...</div>` already exists on the page you would replace

```
alert('You are now logged in. You can add additional actions in the js script.');
```

With

```
$('div.Welcome').html('<span>Welcome...</span>&nbsp;<a href="/logout">Logout</a>');
```

However, note that I removed `{username}`. When the user visits the page while logged out they do not have a username. When they log in via AJAX the page is not refreshed, therefore the username still remains on the server side. Zoo Visitor does not return any member data with it, either.

It might be better for you to just use a regular log in process than use AJAX if you're trying to do app-like stuff.

If you still want to stick to JavaScript for this then one thing you could do is create a template that returns the data via JSON, e.g.

```
{exp:http_header content_type="application/json"}
{ "username": "{username}" }
```

(Note the use of the [http_header](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header) plugin.)

Right after a successful login you would use AJAX to check that template, then confirm the  results. If `username` has a `length` then you know the person is logged in and you can update your Welcome div.

Or... you may want to try logging in via [Open API](http://www.putyourlightson.net/open-api) by Ben Croker. Apparently its authentication returns the member data you're looking for, see http://docs.eeopenapi.apiary.io/#authentication

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!! It help me a lot to understand better javascript usage. And yes you are right, it might be better to use just a regular log process. Regards, Stéphane

Comment: Yes. JavaScript occurs in the browser, PHP on the server, "AJAX" is generally for making a user's experience seemless. However, it may require a little more work for the developer. This is especially the case with AJAX as it is not synchronous, meaning if you use JavaScript to send/get information from a server the rest of your script will not wait for the response and then continue, it is just going to keep running.